# How to delete data from database by using React js and REST API

Tags: reactjs, rest

I am learning REST API. I am using the react app for front end and backend for Node js and express server. For API I am using REST API. I am using MongoDB for the database. I successfully display all the data to the browser. I can able to search the data. Now I want to delete the data. I don't know how to delete data from REST API endpoint. I will be really glad if someone help me out. I tested my backend by using Postman. Everything works fine as expected.

**This is my backend delete end point**

```
app.delete("/students/:id", async (req, res, next) => {
  const id = req.params.id;

  try {
    student
      .remove({ _id: id })
      .exec()
      .then(data => {
        res.json(data);
      });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
});
```

**I export my API END points to React js**

```
 export async function deleteStudent(id) {
  const response = await fetch(`/students/${id}`, {
    method: "DELETE"
  });
  return response.json();
}
```

**This is the main component where I want to delete the data**

```
 import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { logEntry } from "../Api/Api";
import { deleteStudent } from "../Api/Api";

function Datatable() {
  const [total, settotal] = useState([]);
  const [searchItem, setsearchItem] = useState({
    item: ""
  });
  const [data, setdata] = useState([]);

  const handleChange = e => {
    setsearchItem({ item: e.target.value });
  };

  const getEntries = async () => {
    const logEntries = await logEntry();

    console.log(logEntries);
    settotal(logEntries.count);
    setdata(logEntries.students);
  };

  const nameFilter = data.filter(list => {
    return list.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchItem.item.toLowerCase());
  });

  const deleteData = async id => {
    await deleteStudent(id);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getEntries();
  }, []);
  return (
    <div>
      <div style={{ paddingLeft: "800px" }}>
        <input
          placeholder="Search student"
          onChange={handleChange}
          style={{ width: "200px", height: "30px" }}
        />
      </div>
      <p>Total student: {total} </p>
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>City</th>
            <th>Address</th>
            <th>Phone</th>
            <th>Email</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
          {nameFilter === "" ? (
            <p>Student not found</p>
          ) : (
            nameFilter.map(list => {
              return (
                <tr>
                  <td>{list.name}</td>
                  <td>{list.city}</td>
                  <td>{list.address}</td>
                  <td>{list.phone}</td>
                  <td>{list.email}</td>
                  <td>
                    <a
                      className="waves-effect red btn-small"
                      onClick={() => deleteData(list.id)}
                    >
                      Delete
                    </a>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              );
            })
          )}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Datatable;
```

I don't know, Am I doing?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a great start! I'm operating on the understanding that you need to somehow pass the `id` of the `student` you want to delete into the URL in `deleteStudent()` from the 'DELETE' button in your `<DataTable>` component.

So, first, let's refactor your `deleteStudent()` function:

```
export async function deleteStudent(id) {
  const response = await fetch(`/students/${id}`, {
    method: "DELETE",
  });
  return response.json();
}
```

You don't need to send any data with a DELETE request, you just need to hit the correct URL based on the `id`, which we can pass in to the method and dynamically include in the `fetch()` call.

Now, you need to find some way to pass that `id` into the `deleteStudent()` function. From what I can see, you are pulling in the student data here (I've paraphrased this):

```
const getEntries = async () => {

    // students are pulled in, I'm assuming they have an 'id' property that corresponds to the 'id' that MongoDB has them stored under
    const logEntries = await logEntry();

    // and now data references the students
    setdata(logEntries.students);

  };
```

It looks like then you filter the students here:

```
const nameFilter = data.filter(list => {
  return list.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchItem.item.toLowerCase());
});
```

And then render the filtered students with a call to .map(). This is where you can pass the `id` along in the `onClick` handler, assuming that you DO have an `id` field on these `list` elements. If you don't, then you will need to find a way to add the `id` in to this data:

```
nameFilter.map(list => {
  return (
    <tr>
      <td>{list.name}</td>
      <td>{list.city}</td>
      <td>{list.address}</td>
      <td>{list.phone}</td>
      <td>{list.email}</td>
      <td>
        <a
          className="waves-effect red btn-small"
          onClick={() => deleteData(list.id)} // this is where the id should get passed on to the handler, and then dynamically included in the DELETE /students/:id url
        >
          Delete
        </a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  );
})
```

Then, in your `deleteData()` function, you will receive the `id` as a param, and you can call your `deleteStudent(id)` function to make the request to the backend:

```
const deleteData = async id => {
  await deleteStudent(id);
};
```

There are some other things that need work, but you have the general idea correct! I'll give some hints towards further improvements below.

Do these need to be separate, or can they be combined?

```
import { logEntry } from "../Api/Api";
import { deleteStudent } from "../Api/Api";
```

Maybe clean up the DELETE route-handler:

```
app.delete("/students/:id", async (req, res, next) => {

  const id = req.params.id;

  try {
    // generally, Mongoose Model's are represented with TitleCase
    Student
      .remove({ _id: id })
      .exec() // is this needed? https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html#model_Model-remove
      .then(data => {
        res.json(data);
      });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
});
```

There seems to be some extra state/hooks lying around in this Datatable:

```
function Datatable() {

  // ... bunch of code

  // do you need state for this?
  const [removeStudent, setremoveStudent] = useState([]);

  // ... more code

  const getEntries = async () => {

    // ... 

    setremoveStudent(deleteData); // not sure this is needed...
  };
```

Comment: That log entry for pulling the data. It has another endpoint. `export async function logEntry() {
  const response = await fetch("/students");
  return response.json();
}’. for delete used delete entry `export async function deleteStudent(id) {
  const response = await fetch(`/students/${id}`, {
    method: "DELETE"
  });
  return response.json();
}’

Comment: The Namefilter for searching the data.

Comment: I modified as you suggested but the delete button does not work :(

Comment: Yes I understand both of those things. The way you have logEntry imported, it's coming from the same file as deleteStudent, so you can do the same kind of import you used when importing multiple hooks from the 'react' library. The nameFilter searches the data, but is also responsible for rendering it.

Comment: Does not work in what way? Is the 'deleteData' handler running at all, or is the problem with the fetch() request from deleteStudent()?

Comment: I'm assuming that there is an 'id' field for each student (represented by 'list' in your map). When you pull in the students, do they have their id's from the DB attached to them in a property called id?

Comment: I modified by a question, can you able to see what I am doing wrong. I took a course from udemy, and in there the teacher used .exec()

Comment: OK, hopefully we will get kicked into a chat room soon, but I can try and help from comments. Do you understand all of the changes I made, and why they were necessary? If you just copied and pasted the code, that won't help much. We need to step through it and make sure the assumptions I made are correct with the data in your program. So, what data is coming in to the deleteData handler? Is there an ID being passed in at all?

Comment: this is the id looks like _id: "5e7b612c4fd91b29fcc15f81"

Comment: Great! So, that is coming in to the deleteData handler when you click the button?

Comment: This line `onClick={() => deleteData(list.id)}` assumes that this id: `5e7b612c4fd91b29fcc15f81` is on that `list.id` property. If it isn't, then you need to find a way to get it there!

Comment: Since you pull in the students here: `const logEntries = await logEntry();`, whatever is going on in `logEntry()` needs to be attaching those MongoDB _id props to your students, so we can use them in the `map()` call on `nameFilter`

Comment: Can I share with you my GitHub repo?

Comment: Yes, but YOU are manually putting the id into Postman. Your application has to get this ID from that `logEntry()` call I think.

Comment: I am a beginner level coder. Write lots of code. please do not mind.

Comment: No worries, I'm trying to find a place for us to chat in real time

Comment: Log out the 'response' in app.get('/students'), and tell me if the students field has an id prop.

Comment: I got this error in my terminal: (node:24721) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "undefined" at path "_id" for model "Student"

Comment: Here, see if you can type and share code here: https://codeshare.io/5PVgmM

Comment: I still could not fix the PUT method :(